# What's the point of locking a file if you can just catch the exception and try again later?

Tags: java, multithreading, nio, file-locking

I have a program for a short experiment we are running that operates in two modes - 'host' and 'client'. The **host**, of which there is only ever one at a time, writes data to a file on a network drive about every second or so (can be more depending on user input). **Clients** do not write, but read from this file every second to update their state.

A co-worker I mentioned this setup to said that I should include **file-locking** in my code, otherwise things could go "horribly wrong". While I trust their judgement and will do as they suggest (they linked [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/DemonstratesfilelockingandsimplefilereadandwriteoperationsusingjavaniochannelsFileChannel.htm) to me), I am missing something conceptually because I don't understand how there could be any issues if the program still runs fine — I still catch the IO exceptions so I know if they occur (although they haven't so far) — and both the reading and writing is not so critical that any individual missed read/write operation would actually be a loss. It's ok if at one point in time a read fails because a previous thread is mid-write; it'll just be read a second later. Why is file locking needed if you don't care about a few missed operations and the program still runs anyway?

**The code for hosts writing the file:**

```
byte[] bytes = null;
try {
    bytes = Data.getBytes("UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    Files.write(logfile, bytes);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**The code for clients reading the file:**

```
byte[] fileArray = null;  
String fileArrayStr = null;  
try {  
    fileArray = Files.readAllBytes(pathState);  
} catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Java 7 | Windows Vista |

Comment: Why use file locking? Consider how it works if you have two concurrent clients.

Comment: If you catch an exception you shouldn't just print it and pretend it didn't happen. If your encoding doesn't work, you won't be able to write `null`

Comment: Is it acceptable if the client sees a torn write? What if the host is writing, and when only half the data has been written, a client reads and sees a partial update at the end of the file? Will that cause a problem? Remember, `Files.write` or `Files.readAllBytes` might be single lines in your program, but they could translate to multiple system calls to read or write multiple blocks on the filesystem.

Comment: @peter - Oops, yeah I do have a check in there but I inadvertently removed that part when I condensed the code. :)

Comment: @elliot - This whole question is me considering that... so no I don't see a conflict with two applications reading the same file at the same time.

Comment: @DavidConrad - it's acceptable as long as it updates to a correct full read within a few seconds.

Comment: What would be the point if you *couldn't* catch the exception and try again? WhT would you prefer? Exit the process?

Comment: @EJP - Whether or not I could catch the exception, it would be still fine if I could just attempt a read a few seconds later. If I *couldn't* attempt a read a few seconds later (due to a Read/Write conflict), then of course the point of implementing file locking would be so this doesn't occur. But my software *can* try a read again afterwards, so I don't understand where you're going with that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not IO Exceptions to worry about.  It is that clients could be writing data to the same file at the same time.  This could potentially cause an interleaving effect as the different threads (or possibly processes) swap in and out.

Comment: `Clients do not write, but read from this file every second to update their state`

Comment: In that case you should be fine, it is just considered "best" practice to do so

Answer (score 2):

With the clients only reading (and only host writing) you can get away with not using File Locks.  However, when you have multiple clients and/or host writing you want to use File Locks so you don't have concurrent writes to the same file.

It's good practice for you to use File Locks regardless in case the program changes in the future where you could have clients writing.  This would be preemptive planning and good practice.